# Parsing a directory of files with regex and ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to do a simple regex to grab specific text out of a bunch of text files in a directory. The code I'm using is below:

```
input_dir = File.join('path/to/file/dir/', "*.txt")

Dir.glob(input_dir) do |file|
  if /\.txt$/i.match file
    File.open(file, "r") do |_file|
      /==BEGIN==(.*)==END==/.match _file.read
      puts $1
    end
  end
end
```

That works for exactly 1 of the files in the directory, but all other files return nil. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to guess with so little data, but could it be that in most files (except one), `==BEGIN==` and `==END==` are on different lines?

Does `/==BEGIN==(.*)==END==/m.match _file.read` change anything? The `/m` modifier allows the dot to also match newlines in Ruby.

Comment: Also, be aware that `(.*)` matches greedily, which could be a problem if there was more than one `==BEGIN==`/`==END==` pair in a file.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about not explaining more. I was trying to keep the questions simple without dumping my entire text doc into it. That being said, that `m` flag works like a charm. Not sure _why_ it works, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: Well, without it, the dot only matches non-newline characters, so if there is a line break between `==BEGIN==` and `==END==`, the regex fails.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. The thing is that _every_ file has newline characters in it, including the one that worked.

Comment: Huh. Hard to believe :) Can you post the (part of the) file that matched?

Comment: I can if you want, but to make it weirder, when I was initially trying to figure it out, I replaced the entire contents of the file that worked with the contents of a file that did. Saved, re-ran the script, still worked, even with different contents.